# How to Export Data from a Map Service?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, map-service

I'm using a map service which shows points for oil and gas wells.  It's useful to view them in ArcMap, but what I'd really like to do is be able to export them for use in another program, such as AutoCAD.

I don't have the option to right-click and export any of the layers.  I can't select the layers or view an attribute table.

Is this typical behavior with a map service, or is there some way I can export these points (with attributes) to a separate layer?

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 (Basic).  The map service is located [here](https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/DOG_Services/Oilgas_Wells_10_Flex/MapServer).