# Opening KML file from ArcGIS server with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, kml, osgeo

I am able to open the [google KML sample](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) by running:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx( fn, 0 )
```

But when using a specific [file](http://sinupotp.sdp.gov.co:6080/arcgis/rest/services/SERVICIOS_GEOGRAFICOS/BARRIOS_LEGALIZADOS/MapServer) that I get from my country's database, it doesn't work. I've solved the problem by converting the file into a GPX using GPSBabel but I am sure there must be a better way of doing it. By the way when I run on my .gpx:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

# File converted from KML to GPX by GPSBabel.
fn = r"D:\Downloads\POT_DONDE_VIVE_LA_GENTE.gpx"

ds = gdal.OpenEx( fn, 0 )
cnt = ds.GetLayerCount()

for i in range( 0, cnt ):

    print( ds.GetLayer(i).GetExtent() )
```

I get:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

That tells me that there must something wrong. The file works perfectly when using the [ArcGISWebViewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsinupotp.sdp.gov.co%3A6080%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FSERVICIOS_GEOGRAFICOS%2FBARRIOS_LEGALIZADOS%2FMapServer&source=sd).

So my questions are, how can I read KML files that output:

```
IOError: Could not open 'fileName'
```

with GDAL/OSGEO?, and if the only way is to convert them first to a different file format(how to it within python?) how can I be sure that the output of the conversion matches the original file?

Comment: That KML doesn't contain any geometry, it contains a network link to an ArcGIS Server service. You can't open the KML with GDAL.  You might be able to extract a map (picture in jpg or png format) from the WMS that the ArcGIS Server provides.

Comment: So there is no way of getting geo from the ArcGIS servers?

Comment: There's  ~1700 features, you can [grab 100 at a time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40455/2856) using the [query endpoint](http://sinupotp.sdp.gov.co:6080/arcgis/rest/services/SERVICIOS_GEOGRAFICOS/BARRIOS_LEGALIZADOS/MapServer/0/query)

Comment: I found a javascript script that did it for me its called AGStoShapefile.

Comment: Does anyone has a good source to converting Shapefile or GEOJson to raster?

Comment: [`gdal_rasterize`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)

Comment: Yes I know about that function but I haven't been able to implement it, I get an error on the fourth parameter do you know of any example that I could use? The ones I've came across didn't help

Comment: Ask a new question with full details, inc. your error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [user2859](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856) said, the KML from the ArcGIS server only contains a link to the file online, and through the webpage query  you can only download 100 features at a time, but using a script called [AGStoShapefile](https://github.com/tannerjt/AGStoShapefile) I've been able to download the whole layer at a time.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! But for future readers' sake, this doesn't answer the original question, in which you ask how to open KML files using GDAL.

Comment: I've edited the question so that future readers don't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

GDAL doesn't open KML files, but OGR does.

```
from osgeo import ogr

fn = r"D:\Downloads\POT_DONDE_VIVE_LA_GENTE.kml"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
dataSource = driver.Open(fn, 0) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable.
```

There are many code examples here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-feature-count. And the file format code 'KML' can be looked up here: https://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html.

Comment: I have tried that also, and the issue is the file itself as with the code I supplied I am able to open the google sample, so that shouldn't solve the problem, but I am gonna give it a try and let you know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not all KMLs are vector.

Comment: user2856 True, they're mark-up files that might contain vector data, or raster. I've edited my answer to not imply that KML is always vector.

Comment: By the way you don't need ogr gdal.OpenEx() does it as well

Comment: Well not in python but if you are using the C# bindings it does make a difference