# How to, if possible, copy data from an ArcGIS REST Service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-rest-api, error-999999, map-service, copy

I do not believe this is a copy of [Download Dataset From ArcGIS REST Service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40445) or [Extracting data from ArcGIS REST endpoint?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252425) due to the source and type of service.

I would like to copy the features from a government ArcGIS REST Service. It is a MapServer so I am not sure how, or if it is possible. I tried replicating a code I used to copy a FeatureServer but that did not work and instead got an ERROR 999999 which isn't very helpful for diagnosing what is wrong.

The code is as follows:

```
# Set environment options
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True    

# Set workspace 
ws = r'c:/ws'
wsGDB = os.path.join(ws, 'EnvironmentalContamination.gdb')

# MO Hazardous Waste from DNR
conFields = "https://gis.dnr.mo.gov/arcgis/rest/services/e_start/e_start/MapServer/0"
# Copy fc from rest service
conCopy = "MOContamination"
memCon = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(conFields, conCopy)
```

Comment: you need to look at the formats that are available to download - you can check the wizard https://gis.dnr.mo.gov/arcgis/rest/services/e_start/e_start/MapServer/export?bbox=199082.18667357054,3974416.295123932,1027758.8440268853,4540625.760876196

Comment: This works, inside ArcGIS Pro. I added the layer to the map (via URL), then used the layer reference in CopyFeatures. The issue is probably using a **MapService** with CopyFeatures; it probably only supports a **FeatureService**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe **CopyFeatures** can only work directly on a **FeatureService**.
You can make use of `arcpy.FeatureSet` to put a wrapper on the MapService, which CopyFeatures supports.

```
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load("https://gis.dnr.mo.gov/arcgis/rest/services/e_start/e_start/MapServer/0")
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fs, "Foo2")
```

However, this service seems pretty slow. If you run CopyFeatures too soon after doing the *load*, CopyFeatures will still fail as the data hasn't been brought down.

Comment: Would adding some kind of python code to tell it to 'stall' or wait after loading make sense then?

Comment: Hm..even with a 5 minute sleep delay, I'm only getting a single record using this.